# Partial View Dialog Events Do Not Work in Chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

A partial view page (cshtml) is opened as a dialog by angularjs by a window click in a parent view page (cshtml), but the embedded component in the dialog does not respond to mouse inputs - eg it does not respond to clicks in chrome although it does in ie11.

specifically, I have a FileUltimate file browser control in the partial view page opened as a dialog. the cshtml is:

```
@using GleamTech.FileUltimate
@model FileManager

@using MyCompany.OWL.Website.Helpers
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<head>
    <title>File Browser</title>
    @Html.RenderCss(Model)
    @Html.RenderJs(Model)
</head>


<div class="overlay" id="fileBrowser">
    <h1>File Manager<a href data-icon="&#x00d7;" data-ng-click="close()"></a></h1>
    <div>
        <div style="width:800px">
            @Html.RenderControl(Model)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

it is opened by an angularjs controller for the parent page

```
$scope.openFileManager = function () {
    var modalItem = { project: $scope.item };
    fileManager.openFileManager(modalItem);
};
```

which in turn calls

```
fileManagerFactory.factory('FileManager', ['$modal', function ($modal) {

    return {
        openFileManager: function (data) {

            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: '/filemanager/filemanager?projectid=' + data.project.projectId,
                controller: 'FileManagerController',
                resolve: {
                    projectData: function () {
                        return data;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };

}]);
```

the associated mvc controller for the partial view is

```
[AccessAuthorize(Roles = "ProjectManagers")]
public ActionResult FileManager(int ProjectID)
{
    FileManagerApiController api = new FileManagerApiController();

    //return View(new[] { fileManager }); 

    return PartialView("_FileManager",api.Get(ProjectID));
}
```

I am stumped for reasons why ie11 dialogs would work, but chrome and firefox would not. some keyboard input is processed by chrome, but no mouse. the failure is only on the fileultimate control. Does anyone know why the control does not respond in chrome? is it angularjs?

since the vendor does not believe that his control has a problem, I am exploring other ways of opening it without embedding it in a dialog cshtml, but my biggest problem is passing data from the parent view to the mvc controller of the file browser. the data is held in the html controls of the parent page and $scope variable which seems to preclude calling the control in a @Html.BeginForm. the file browser can only be opened after it is configured with record specific data in the parent window, and I cannot navigate away from the parent page. the file browser has its own stand alone ui.

ps - one other odd observance is that ie11, chrome44, and firefox33 render the dialog differently - 3 different renditions of the same cshtml.

Comment: Do you have a element with the name filebrowser anywhere in the dialog's view?

Comment: in the first code snippet there is a div <div class="overlay" id="fileBrowser">. I corrected the case from the first post but it is there.

Comment: I was asking if you have two elements with the same ID in the dom at the same time.

Comment: I didn't find any, but then again chrome 44 does not appear to have a dom search ability which makes it useless.

Comment: with further research, I can confirm that the issue is not chrome per se. a very simple application using the control with chrome succeeds. so I suspect that there some libraries or configurations elsewhere in the application which chrome does not like.